# How can I put each image on a different page with the itextpdf library?

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf, mobile, itext

I am using the ItextPDF library to create pdf from images, this is my function who does all the work:

```
private fun pdf(name: String, tamanio: PageSize, listOfURIs: List<Uri>) {
    Log.d("PDF", "PDF file name: ${getUniqueName(name)}")

    // Directory where the PDF file will be stored
    val outputPdfDir = documentsDirectory
    outputPdfDir.mkdirs()// Create the directory if it does not exist
 
    // Full path of the output PDF file
    val outputPdfFilePath = File(outputPdfDir, getUniqueName(name))
    Log.d("PDF", "Set output $outputPdfFilePath")

    // Create a new PDF document
    val pdfWriter = PdfWriter(outputPdfFilePath)
    val pdfDocument = PdfDocument(pdfWriter)
    pdfDocument.defaultPageSize = tamanio

    val document = Document(pdfDocument)

    for (uri in URIList) {
        val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri.path)

        // Convert the image into a byte array
        val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, byteArrayOutputStream)
        val byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()
  
        // Create an image from the byte array
        val imageData = ImageDataFactory.create(byteArray)
        val image = Image(imageData)
 
        val newPage = pdfDocument.addNewPage(tamanio)

        //resize the image to the page
        image.scaleToFit(newPage.pageSize.width, newPage.pageSize.height)

        //top and left margin to 0
        image.setFixedPosition(0f, 0f)

        // Add the image to the PDF document
        document.add(image)
    }

    //close the document
    document.close()

    // Display a success message
    Toast.makeText(this, "PDF created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    Log.d("PDF", "PDF created at ${outputPdfFilePath.absolutePath}")

    // Navigate back to the main activity
    val intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(intent)
    finish()

    Toast.makeText(this, "PDF created successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

With that code, what I get is the same number of sheets in the PDF as the number of images in the list, but when I place the images in the PDF, they are all placed one on top of the other on the first page. I would like to be able to have each image on a dedicated page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intent to add a new image into a new page of pdf then you can always do it using this API call once the image is added which is after document.add(image).
document.add(new AreaBreak());